# Google Analytics: Invalid JWT Signature (invalid_grant) when trying to make authorized API call

Tags: rest, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, jwt

I trying to make authorized API call (HTTP/REST) to service account in Google Analytics.
using this doc: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I just use HTTP/REST request to test.

So I have service account's private key file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "test-x",
  "private_key_id": "some_private_key_id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- some_private_key -----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "client_email": "test-01@test-x.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "some_client_id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test-01%40test-x.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I create JWT based on
client_email: 
test-01@test-x.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Header:

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
```

Claim set:

```
{
  "iss": "test-01@test-x.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
  "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "exp": 1488820112,
  "iat": 1488816522
}
```

**iat** - I just set current

**exp** - current + 1 hour,

I use this service to create signature: https://jwt.io/#debugger

It generates encoded value which I try to use for access token request

When I try to use generated result from "Encoded" field:

```
curl -d 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=JWT_that_has_been_signed' https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

result:

```
{
 "error": "invalid_grant",
 "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

But I not use my private key.
Accordingly to documentation for computing the signature I have to use my private key.
I not completely understand how to use key in right way to compute the signature correctly.

jwt.io already generates PUBLIC and PRIVATE key...

Probably I'm using jwt.io incorrectly..

Please advise me the correct way of creating JWT or may be another service to create it.

Thanks!

Comment: have u found any solution

Comment: I did not found how to figure out in that way.
Alternatively I used  Google Analytics API client.

Comment: I used this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-jwt and i am getting token successfully. hope it may help others who are facing similar problem

Comment: I was getting this error, the client_email was wrong

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when the secrets key was no longer valid. I generated a new service account key and it started working.

Comment: Although the key had not expired, creating a new one fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone exploring this issue, I have a set of code in PHP to get the token with the JSON service account file. This PHP snippet will get you a token to use to get GA data.

```php
    // assume $config is your json service account file converted to array
    $config = "YOUR JSON FILE CONVERTED TO ARRAY";
    $jwt_header = '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}';
    $jwt_header_cryph = urlencode(base64_encode($jwt_header));
    
    $jwt_claim = '{
                "iss": "'.$config['client_email'].'",
                "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
                "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                "exp":'.(time()+3600).',
                "iat":'.time().'
            }';
    
    $jwt_claim_cryph = urlencode(base64_encode($jwt_claim));
    
    $data = $jwt_header_cryph.".".$jwt_claim_cryph;
    
    $binary_signature = "";
    
    $algo = "SHA256";
    openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $config['private_key'], $algo);
    $jws_signature_cryph = urlencode(base64_encode($binary_signature));
    
    //concatenating the jwt request to complete it
    $complete_request = $jwt_header_cryph.".".$jwt_claim_cryph.".".$jws_signature_cryph;
    
    //build CURL request with post method
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
    
    //set POST variables
    $fields = array(
        'grant_type' => urlencode('urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'),
        'assertion' => $complete_request
    );
    
    $fields_string = "";
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $token = json_decode($result, true);
```

The variable `$token` will have the following content

```php
    [
      "access_token" => "your-access-token-string"
      "expires_in" => 3599
      "token_type" => "Bearer"
    ]
```

Use the `access_token` string to ping GA for analytics data.

Hopefully this helps someone along as this is not well explained much anywhere and it took some digging to figure out the encryption properly.

Comment: Much useful. I was using the .pem file instead of the json file generated from the Service Account. This helps me to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue , 
I just create a new private key from `google cloud platform`

```
  IAM & admin -> Service accounts
```

`Service accounts for project` "**Project_Name**"

already created your Service account,click on the `actions-> Create Key`

and update the private key on your project. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used wrong `service account ID`.

You are able to find correct on under:
Google console -> Service Account -> Detail -> Unique ID

I must be a long number like: 113334445551115554321

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a wrong time zone on my system.

I reinstalled my system and did not spot that the time was not set correctly.