# GCP: "Invalid JWT Signature" when using Service Account JSON

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google's gRPC library to access data from my GCP domain.
My code performs authentication using a service account JSON key.
It worked fine for about a month, until recently I started receiving the following error on any action I try to perform:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
```

I should note that the authentication process executes without errors, as does creation of the service object (see Java code example below). The error is thrown when I try to perform any data access action, e.g. the listSecrets method in the example below.

Searching for this problem on the web, I have found mainly answers that point to a system time/timezone error; however, the date & time & timezone on my computer are completely accurate.
Any suggestions?

Example of my Java code:

```
String projectId = "my-project";
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\elisha.l\\Downloads\\co-club-project-01-3588a3330456.json"));
SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create();
ProjectName parent = ProjectName.of(projectId);
ListSecretsPagedResponse response = client.listSecrets(parent);
```

Stacktrace of the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1050)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1176)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:969)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:760)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:434)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:763)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:742)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.listSecrets(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:245)
        at com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient.listSecrets(SecretManagerServiceClient.java:196)
        at google.Secret.main(Secret.java:26)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Credentials failed to obtain metadata
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:444)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)
    at com.google.auth.Credentials.blockingGetToCallback(Credentials.java:112)
    at com.google.auth.Credentials$1.run(Credentials.java:98)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1113)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: To look for a common issue, can you provide a timestamp with timezone when you last saw the error?

Comment: @MrTech, sure. Just a minute ago: 2020-10-01T11:36:36.224+03:00[Asia/Jerusalem]

Comment: I wasn't able to find a common issue at that time but was able to find this thread with many things to try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651549/google-analytics-invalid-jwt-signature-invalid-grant-when-trying-to-make-auth

Comment: I got this error because  my system time was running fast.

Answer (score 0):

> I should note that the authentication process executes without errors, as does creation of the service object (see Java code example below). The error is thrown when I try to perform any data access action, e.g. the listSecrets method in the example below.

I think you are saying that the instantiation of the GoogleCredentials and SecretManagerServiceClient objects do not throw any exceptions. But these don't actually validate your credentials until you invoke a method on the client object, like `listServices`. (Please let me know if I misunderstood and *some* methods on the SecretManagerServiceClient actually validate properly and succeed).

It seems like there is some issue with your service account JSON key, so I would start by determining if it works separately from the Java code. You can follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/getting-started#test to use oauth2l to get a bearer token from your service account, then invoke the secret manager API directly using this bearer token via curl, as shown in https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets. Something like:

```
curl "https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/secrets?secretId=secret-id" \
    --request "POST" \
    --header "authorization: Bearer <bearer token from oauth2l>" \
    --header "content-type: application/json" \
    --header "x-goog-user-project: project-id" \
    --data "{\"replication\": {\"automatic\": {}}}"
```

If that works whereas the Java code does not, then you will probably want to proceed by filing an issue on the https://github.com/googleapis/java-secretmanager repository.

Alternatively to all of the above: it may be quicker just to create a new service account and see if that works, versus debugging precisely what's going wrong with the current account.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Creating a new service account did not solve the problem; however, invoking the API directly worked fine. The problem isn't exclusive to the Secret Manager API; I'm experiencing the same problem with other Google Compute Engine and Security Manager APIs as well.

Comment: I would file an issue for this with either the java-secretmanager repository or https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java.