# Using gspread without having service account

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, gspread

Can I use `gspread` without having a secret key and service account? I was using the default authentication and it worked before. But suddenly, it starts to throw this error

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})
```

I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651549/google-analytics-invalid-jwt-signature-invalid-grant-when-trying-to-make-auth) had been solved by having a new secret key, but my question is, can I edit my public spreadsheet without having a service account?

I tried this code. It was working but now it doesn't.

```py
def get_gspread() -> gspread.client.Client:
    credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
    return gspread.authorize(credentials)

def get_worksheet(gs, url) -> any:
    sh = gs.open_by_url(url)
    return sh.get_worksheet_by_id(0)

gs = get_gspread()
ws = get_worksheet(gs, public_URL)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `my question is can I use it without having a service account?`. In your expected goal, do you want to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with OAuth2 instead of the service account?

Comment: I'm aiming to edit my public spreadsheets without having a service account.

Comment: Every GCloud project has a default service account that is used with the default authentication. If the default doesn't work for you, then maybe the default service account of your project was removed/deleted? Maybe you can test it with a new fresh Gcloud project?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I'm aiming to edit my public spreadsheets without having a service account.`, in your expected goal, do you want to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with OAuth2 instead of the service account?